# Error 1067 in starting Xampp Mysql in Windows with linux like config signature

Tags: mysql, xampp, startup-error

I said "Linux-like config signature", which means I'm trying to run Mysql in Windows but mysql error shows linux-like file path.

I'm new to Xampp and I don't know exactly how it works.I simply runned xampp setup tool from Xampp control panel.

I try to carry Xampp with my Portable HDD and set-up xampp in portable mode.It works in my own computer but in all the other computers,Mysql didn't start with error 1067.I found this console output.

Even in my local computer,when I tried to setup Xampp for the first time,I had to put the whole Xampp directory into Local C: drive and after setup I've to copy the folder from C: to my External HDD.Then setup again.If I setup from HDD for the first time,the above error comes out even in my own local computer. **"My external HDD have a ext4 partition and NTFS partition."** I think the error comes out because Xampp set-up tools finds the ext4 partition and it thinks that my OS is Linux when it first run in my external HDD.

```
E:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysqld --console
121127 14:36:42 [Warning] Can't create test file \usr\local\mysql\data\W39.lower
-test
121127 14:36:42 [Warning] Can't create test file \usr\local\mysql\data\W39.lower
-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '\usr\local\\mysql\data\' (Errcode: 2)
121127 14:36:42 [ERROR] Aborting

121127 14:36:42 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Those are not really 'linux style pathes', since every operating system except MS-Windows does use foreward slashes (`/`) instead of the MS-Windows style backward variant (`\\`). MySQL aparently reads a configuration meant for a unix like system (probably simply the default) but runs in a MS-Windows style system without the configuration having been adopted. I suggest you check the configuration for that path and change it to whatever makes sense in your system.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But let me know how to change the path.I'm a newbie.

Comment: I can't find such `\usr\local\ ` path even in `E:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` file.

Comment: No, look for `/usr/local` instead. The default most likely is in unix path notation and I guess mysql just adapts that option to your systems style. Maybe there is an additional system wide configuration installed when you unpacked that package? Sorry, I have very limited knowledge of MS-Windows myself...

Comment: I mean I can't found even `usr` text in the file.

Comment: Then maybe it is _not_ specified in the configuration but a builtin fallback if _no_ configuration is given. Check the manual and add that configuration, I'd suggest. Although I am a little surprised: I heard little issues about startup configuration from prople who use packages like that xampp. I'd assume the default configuration _usually_ us just fine for beginners purposes. Maybe something went wrong during your installation?

Comment: The package version is "Apache Friends XAMPP (Basis Package) version 1.7.3". I got the zip file from my friend and just unzip and run the setup from Xampp control panel.That's all.The one thing I noticed is my external HDD have a ext4 partition and a NTFS patition.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot be of further help with issues details on MS-Windows systems. I suggest you consult the projects homepage, most likely they have some sort of FAQ list and a forum.

Comment: I can't find any FAQ but I downloaded the latest portable Xampp.It runs smoothly.Everything is OK.I don't want to waste my time anymore.:)

Comment: Wow. In that case I suggest you ask yourself a few questions about that package you got from your friend... And _maybe_ also about your _friend_... but great you got going nevertheless! Have fun playing with that stuff!

Comment: Oh, and just a side remark: Maybe this motivates you to take a look at an operating system that offers a software management system and reliable repositories where you can install packages with a single click from, packages that have been specially prepared for your system. MS-Windows is so backwards and insecure if it comes to software installation... it uses wild west principles...

Comment: Sorry! I don't understand.I'm not an English.

Comment: Your English is perfectly fine! What I meant was: how come your friend gives you a package that was obviously manipulated? Installating some software 'someone gave you' or you 'found on some internet site' is always a huge security risk. You don't know what is in that package. Don't do that! Look for trusted sources.

Comment: My friend is not interest in Programming.He just collect computer tools from others.But I also found some kind of virus in the programming tools zip file where the xampp is packed.But I saw that the Xampp runs sometimes soomthly in my own computer which is not connected to the intenet but mysql never startup in computers of internet cafe.

Comment: I did not want to imply your friend has manipulated that package with bad intentions! But this is such a typical thing: people get some package somewhere, know nothing about it, install it and *bang*. you were lucky, the software just didn't work. What if it would have deleted your harddrive? Or sent all your privat data somewhere? Or sent all your friends obscene insults? When you install a software on MS-Windows then each time you hand over full administrative rights to someone you don't know. That is not only insecure, it is insane.

Comment: Yes.I understand what you said.My problem is internet connection.My country gave poor internet connection.So it was very convenient for me to get ready-downloaded tools from friends.But now the government can afford about 20 kB/s for 1 person.This is a lesson for me.thanks